# How can i load an HTML code in a UIWebView?

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview

My data is coming from the servers and I am storing it in a dictionary. There is a key called description in the dictionary which contains the HTML code for the description. I don't want to save the HTML code in a file because the dictionary contains a lot more dictionaries with similar description key within each. I want to load the HTML file on the UIWebView directly from the code.
Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try to solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
NSString *htmlString = [result objectforKey:@"HtmlValue"];
 [webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:Nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [webview loadHTMLString:stringName baseURL:Nil];
```

Also Visit [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it will be more helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

Add file.html in your project resources.
Use this code to load in the web view:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [_helpWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```